# Send http request with ajax and wait

Tags: ajax, curl, webserver

I'm trying to make with AJAX a HTTP request to my server, but in my server there are going to be two curl requests.

One of them is going to be faster, can I just send a JSON to the frontend and when I have the other respone send another JSON?
How I catch the first and second JSON through AJAX?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying you want to send two AJAX requests?  Do you want to send them concurrently (at the same time), or do you want to send them serially (one after the other)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is only one request (fired through AJAX) but two responses (from the server) to that request. Is it possible?

No, that's not possible. HTTP is a request-response protocol. Each request gets one response. Your page user doesn't need to know that multiple requests have been send though. They won't notice.

You *can* fix it server-side. Your server-side should fetch the two requests, wait untill they finish and than compose one answer out of the two. That combined answer can be send to the client. That way there is one request-response between the client and the server and two request-response between your server and a 3rd party.

To clarify, this is what you'll get than:

```
 browser          server            3rd party
          request
   |---------------->|
   |                 | proxy
   |                 |       req1
   |                 |----------------->| 
   |                 |<-----------------|
   |                 |       req2
   |                 |----------------->|
   |     response    |<-----------------|
   |<----------------|
```

My original assumption was that you'd want to do:

```
 browser          server            3rd party
          request
   |---------------->|
   |                 | proxy
   |                 |       req1
   |                 |----------------->| 
   |      response   |<-----------------|
   |<----------------|
   |                 |
   |      request    |
   |---------------->|
   |                 |       req2
   |                 |----------------->|
   |     response    |<-----------------|
   |<----------------|
```

which (depending on your requirements) *might* be compacted to:

```
 browser          3rd party
          request
   |---------------->|
   |      response   |
   |<----------------|
   |                 
   |      request    
   |---------------->|
   |     response    |
   |<----------------|
```

which could be a lot easier.

(Started typing this as a comment to your comment on my last answer, but it gets a little complex, so that's why I'm making it a separate answer, sorry about that.)

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. I wanted to know for not wasting so much time to make the requests because each request made from the browser has to collect data through curl in the server.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

basically the first A in Ajax is for a-synchronous, so firing off two different requests and expecting them to run in parrallel is the default. Each call will have a callbackhandler that could check some state object on the page if both requests have finished. So the magic will need to happen in the callback handlers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, I may haven't explained well. There is only one request (fired through AJAX) but two responses (from the server) to that request. Is it possible?